# copy certain spaces from a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which looks like this

```
   18DMA      H 9996   0.886   5.687   5.320
   18DMA      H 9997   1.019   5.764   5.247
   18DMA     Np 9998   0.947   5.584   5.151
   18DMA      H 9999   1.033   5.541   5.113
   18DMA     Cn10000   0.880   5.674   5.050
   18DMA      H10001   0.831   5.616   4.971
   18DMA      H10002   0.814   5.751   5.091
   18DMA      H10003   0.957   5.735   5.003
   18DMA     Cn10004   0.837   5.486   5.185
```

The desire output is to delete column 3 however since from a certain row/line and next there is no a space between atom name and number I cannot make the deletion by column. Is there any way to make the deletion by selecting certain number of characters? The desire output should be

```
   18DMA      H    0.886   5.687   5.320
   18DMA      H    1.019   5.764   5.247
   18DMA     Np    0.947   5.584   5.151
   18DMA      H    1.033   5.541   5.113
   18DMA     Cn    0.880   5.674   5.050
   18DMA      H    0.831   5.616   4.971
   18DMA      H    0.814   5.751   5.091
   18DMA      H    0.957   5.735   5.003
   18DMA     Cn    0.837   5.486   5.185
```

Comment: clarify your *atom name and number*

Comment: My problem is in line 18DMA     Cn10000   0.880   5.674   5.050 since there is no space between Cn and 1000 so I cannot proceed with copying the desire column. Somehow I need instead of copying a column to copy certain characters to make it work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't have `<TAB>`s but multiple spaces as field separators, and by looking at and counting your sample data, I came up with

```
  $ sed -E 's/^(.{15}).{5}/\1/' file
   18DMA      H   0.886   5.687   5.320
   18DMA      H   1.019   5.764   5.247
   18DMA     Np   0.947   5.584   5.151
   18DMA      H   1.033   5.541   5.113
   18DMA     Cn   0.880   5.674   5.050
   18DMA      H   0.831   5.616   4.971
   18DMA      H   0.814   5.751   5.091
   18DMA      H   0.957   5.735   5.003
   18DMA     Cn   0.837   5.486   5.185
```

It's using a "back reference" for the first 15 characters to restore them using `\1`
in the replacement part of the `s`ubstitute command.

Answer (score 8):

Use `cut` in character mode:

```
cut -c1-15,21-
```

you may need to tweak the exact character numbers.
Again, this assumes the input doesn't use TABs (`\t` characters) as delimiters (which it probably doesn't, since then you wouldn't have the problem of the joined fields in the first place).

If there are tabs, then the `expand` program can convert them to spaces.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF == 5 { sub("[0-9]*$", "", $2) } NF == 6 { $0 = $1 OFS $2 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 } { print }' file
18DMA   H       0.886   5.687   5.320
18DMA   H       1.019   5.764   5.247
18DMA   Np      0.947   5.584   5.151
18DMA   H       1.033   5.541   5.113
18DMA   Cn      0.880   5.674   5.050
18DMA   H       0.831   5.616   4.971
18DMA   H       0.814   5.751   5.091
18DMA   H       0.957   5.735   5.003
18DMA   Cn      0.837   5.486   5.185
```

This short `awk` program will do different things to the input line depending on whether it contains 5 or 6 whitespace-delimited fields.

If it contains five fields, it removes all digits from the end of the second fields and leaves the rest as it is.  If it contains six fields, it rewrites the line but omits the third field.

The output will be tab-delimited (or delimited by whatever you set `OFS` to on the command line).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `vim`?

```
vim +"%s/\([A-Za-z]\)\@<=\s\?\d\+//g" +"w file1" +"q\!" file
```

this `regex` in the vim `command` finds the exact pattern, deletes them and saves the file as file1 and quits `vim`. Your desired formatted things are now in `file1`.
See, `vim` is ultimately **poor man's** `sed`,`awk`,`perl -e 's/.../'`,`tr`,`cut` and many more altogether.

**NB**: This will also work with `vi`. The slash before the bang ( \! ) escapes the bang. The regex is vim-flavored.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would first "fix" the original, and then simply delete the column. You can do both in a single pass, though:

```
awk '{sub(/[0-9]+/," &",$2); $0=$0; $3=""; print}' input_file

18DMA H  0.886 5.687 5.320
18DMA H  1.019 5.764 5.247
18DMA Np  0.947 5.584 5.151
18DMA H  1.033 5.541 5.113
18DMA Cn  0.880 5.674 5.050
18DMA H  0.831 5.616 4.971
18DMA H  0.814 5.751 5.091
18DMA H  0.957 5.735 5.003
18DMA Cn  0.837 5.486 5.185
```

The `$0=$0` assignment will cause `awk` to recompute (and re-split) the current line. Unlike all other answers, this only make assumptions about the possible format of the 2nd field, not about the length or the number of the fields.

A version that will use Tab as the output field separator:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{sub(/[0-9]+/," &",$2); $0=$0; $3=""; sub(OFS OFS,OFS); print}' input_file

18DMA   H       0.886   5.687   5.320
18DMA   H       1.019   5.764   5.247
18DMA   Np      0.947   5.584   5.151
18DMA   H       1.033   5.541   5.113
18DMA   Cn      0.880   5.674   5.050
18DMA   H       0.831   5.616   4.971
18DMA   H       0.814   5.751   5.091
18DMA   H       0.957   5.735   5.003
18DMA   Cn      0.837   5.486   5.185
```

The extra `sub(OFS OFS, OFS)` will collapse the empty field created by `$3=""`. That should only be necessary if the file is to be processed by a tool which is specifically expecting tab-delimited fields, or for esthetical reasons.

Comment: Although column is not deleted using this approach, just emptied.  If tabs were used for field delimiter, you would still have an empty column where the column 3 data used to be.

Comment: @Kusalananda added tab delimited version

Comment: For the record: the fields from the output of the 2nd version are separated by tabs, and there isn't any tab/empy column/tab or trailing tabs. It's the R-word web interface which is messing up whitespaces -- **why?** (fwiw, it's perfectly possible to preserve tabs in html by using a `<pre>`); how are people able to post makefiles and diffs here?

Comment: Code posted here are for illustration. One is supposed read and understand the code (Makefile or otherwise) and to know where there are tabs and where there are spaces. If it's unclear, it's helpful to point this out. Code posted here are not meant for thinkless copying and pasting (that goes for the rest of the web too, obviously).

Comment: So not being able to exchange accurate diff(1)s is a feature now? LOL.

Comment: I've been here for over seven years, and I've yet to see the need to exchange a diff here. Discussion are more often about the tools and procedures. An answer wold possibly say how to produce a diff, not "here's a diff that will fix your problem".